# How can I add an event listener to each button for a table row result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, dom-events

In my rails app, I am loading a table from an `@results` variable such that each table row is a `@result`. For each `@result` table row I'm looking to have buttons associated with that `@result`. I'm trying to use a Javascript eventlistener for each button and then listen for the event in the js.erb file

When running the app, it looks like only the first row of button has the event listener, how can I fix this?

Also, how would I be able to pass my `@result` to my Javascript so I can utilize parts of that object?

I'm trying to do this through Javascript as I'd like to copy something in to the clipboard and save a file onto the computer.

js.erb

```
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.button1');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

# work with the @result that was clicked over here
});
```

html.erb

```
<% @results.each { |result|  %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= result[:id] %></td>
      <td> 
        <button class="button1"> B1 </button> 
        <button class="button2"> B2 </button> 
        <button class="button3"> B3 </button> 
      </td>
    </tr>

    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed add an event listener to every element. The issue is `document.querySelector` will return the first first matched element. To get all of them, you would use `document.querySelectorAll`. We could rewrite your JavaScript to:

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.button1');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(btns, function addClickListener(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // code here to handle click
  });
});
```

Note that `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which is like an array but unfortunately not an array. So it doesn't have `forEach` and similar methods found on the `Array` class. Thus the work around above to iterate over the nodes by using `forEach` from `Array.prototype`.

However, a much better approach is to listen for events up at the parent element or container for your form or at the document level. Events bubble up so you can listen to the click event once and filter to only the type you want to respond to. That would be one event listener instead of N (where N is the number of buttons).

Comment: Hey @cymen, thanks for your answer! Would you know then how I can use the "@result" associated with the button called?

Comment: @chonglawr I'd suggest posting another question but one way is to put an id for the result or some other attribute on the DOM button element and then on click, use that id to determine which one was clicked on. There are other ways too but lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you incremented the numbers of each `className` like `button1`, `button2` and called in javascript only class `button1` in order to call all `button1`'s you need to give class `button1` to each of your buttons in HTML.

EDIT: Try the code below then.

```
var button1 = document.getElementsByClassName("button1");
Object.keys(button1).map( function (key) {
    var button = button1[key] 
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("button1")
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I just didn't include the rest of the buttons in my example. What I have is a 3 buttons for each table row, so there are multiple buttons with class="button1" and I want all of class button 1 to have an event listener and listen for when they are called so I can do something with their @result

Comment: There was some error in getting it to work, so I used @cymen's code. Do you know how I would be able to reference the '@result' that the button was clicked with?